# app.config/web.config but which one?

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I'm really confused with configuration file in .NET especially with entity framework and logging tool

As many developer I work on a project with one solution but many projects. To keep things simple let's say I work with only 2 projects, 2 layers: Data layer and Interface layer. Interface is my main project and Data is a class library referenced into Interface project. My Data layer contains a reference to NLog and use NLog, but not my Interface layer. Where should I keep the NLog config? In the config file from Data or Interface project?

It seems my launch project need all information from all config file from all dependencies. I have no problem with that but it's not possible to auto generate a combination of all config I need during de build ?

Comment: the .config files are generally per web application or per process. im not sure i understand the question.

Comment: yeah but do you work with more than one project? Do you use EF? Do you use NLog? ".config files are generally per web application or per process" yes but no it doesn't work if you only put data related to the projet in the config file of the project.

Comment: i have worked with more than one project.

Comment: @Daniel A. I just tested my code. My method ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DBServ").ToLower written in VB in my VB layer Data retrieve the values from my app.config from Interface project written in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do the two layers communicate?

If your Data layer is a standalone web app or windows service it should have its own .config.

If it's a class library project, the only .config that matters is the one of your interface project.

Comment: It's a class library project. Yes I should explain it like that. Thank you. I will precise your answer. At run time only .config file from main project matters. But in case of EF when importing database schema the local config file is used. Right ?